# System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send() Timeout SmtpException

Tags: c#, email

I want to Send `Email` via `GMail`

I can send Email via Gmail at home

but `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send()` return `Timeout SmtpException` in company's closed network with same code

I'm going to ask network administrator about this.

Network administrator don't know about address/port information that gmail use so I have to know what address/port need to check before asking I try to connect `[address:smtp.gmail.com, port:587]` with `telnet` and successfully connected.

Are there more to check/open a network address/port?

Comment: Show us the code that is causing you the problem.

Comment: It is not code problem. It works well at home

Comment: Why port 587 ? is that the port you use in the code? or in the app/web.config?

Comment: 587 is Gmail SMTP port (TLS)

Comment: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78775?hl=en

Comment: Use `EnableSsl = true`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `EnableSsl = true`

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
            {
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myusername@gmail.com", "mypwd"),
                EnableSsl = true
            };
            client.Send("myusername@gmail.com", "myusername@gmail.com", "test", "testbody");
            Console.WriteLine("Sent");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

FYI Gmail requires authentication:

```
Outgoing Mail (SMTP) Server
requires TLS or SSL: smtp.gmail.com (use authentication)
Use Authentication: Yes
Port for TLS/STARTTLS: 587
Port for SSL: 465
```

Comment: The OP clearly says the code works at his home, but not at work, how is what you suggest going to change that?

Comment: @SteenT: It uses TLS. So use enableSsl= "true" for enabling TLS. SSL & TSL actually equivalent - TLS is kind of broader than SSL.
As per [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.enablessl.aspx), that will force SMTPClient to use [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3207.txt) 3207 (and RFC uses both terms TLS/SSL).

Comment: So it could work, at his home, without TLS and SSL, but need it from his work network?

Comment: Thanks for answer but @SteenTøttrup is right. I did set EnableSsl. It is not code problem. Totally same code work well at home.